# Doctrine extension: generate slug before flushing to database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, stofdoctrineextensions

Using the `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` (for Symfony)  I generate a slug for my entity `Institution` based on its attribute `internationalName` like this:

**Institution.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"internationalName"})
 */
private $slug;
```

In my config settings i have set `sluggable: true` and generating the unique slug works as expected when creating a new `Institution` or updating an existing one.

I need the generated slug in the controller before flushing to the database. The problem is, the slug is generated when the new entity is flushed to the database. I have searched for this issue and discover two questions with no satisfying answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749923/symfony-vichuploaderbundle-file-name-could-not-be-generated/35752076) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369919/generate-slug-in-prepersist-lifecycle-for-symfony2-with-stofdoctrineextensionsbu).

The best suggestion changing the `getSlug()` in the Entity like this:

```
public function getSlug()
{
    if (!$this->slug) {
        return Urlizer::urlize($this->getInternationalName());
    }
    return $this->slug;
}
```

However, the `internationalName` for my entity does not have to be unique, so the 'pre-flushed slug' can be an existing one if the `internationalName` already exists in the database, which creates a problem in my controller.

Is there a solution to generating a unique slug pre-flush?

Comment: Why do you need the slug before flushing? If you use the slug before flushing, you're not sure it's the same slug after flushing. Otherwise, check `\Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener::makeUniqueSlug` and re-use that logic.

Comment: @StephanVierkant, the Entity is created together with one or more uploaded files. I want these files to be named based on the slug of the Entity, which is turn is based on the `internationalName`. Now you would say, just base it directly on the `internationalName`, but the problem is for two entities with the same name, the file will overwrite.

Comment: Why can't you upload the files after flushing?

Comment: @StephanVierkant, I am using the Vich Uploaderbundle which takes care of the uploading, with that it seems it is not possible.